# Kotlin use Java callback interface

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

I have a WebView. I want to call

```
public void evaluateJavascript(String script, ValueCallback<String> resultCallback)
```

this method.

Here is the ValueCallback interface:

```
public interface ValueCallback<T> {
    /**
     * Invoked when the value is available.
     * @param value The value.
     */
    public void onReceiveValue(T value);
};
```

Here is my kotlin code:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("a", ValueCallback<String> {
            // cant override function
        })
```

Anyone have idea to override the onReceiveValue method in kotlin?
I tried the "Convert Java to Kotlin" but result is the next:

```
v.evaluateJavascript("e") {  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following line is called a [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

```
v.evaluateJavascript("e", { value ->
  // Execute onReceiveValue's code
})
```

Whenever a Java interface has a single method, Kotlin allows you to pass in a lambda instead of an object that implements that interface.

Since the lambda is the last parameter of the `evaluateJavascript` function, you can move it outside of the brackets, which is what the Java to Kotlin conversion did:

```
v.evaluateJavascript("e") { value ->
  // Execute onReceiveValue's code
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You already are. The content between your braces is the content of the `onReceive` function. Kotlin has automatic handling for SAM conversions from Java. All of the following are equivalent.

```
// Use Kotlin's SAM conversion
webView.evaluateJavascript("a") {
    println(it)  // "it" is the implicit argument passed in to this function
}

// Use Kotlin's SAM conversion with explicit variable name
webView.evaluateJavascript("a") { value ->
    println(value)
}

// Specify SAM conversion explicitly
webView.evalueateJavascript("a", ValueCallback<String>() {
    println(it)
})

// Use an anonymous class
webView.evalueateJavascript("a", object : ValueCallback<String>() {
    override fun onReceiveValue(value: String) {
        println(value)
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure about those close bracket `)` positions in first two?

Comment: Yes, it's a feature of Kotlin. From the docs: "In Kotlin, there is a convention that if the last parameter to a function is a function, and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument, you can specify it outside of parentheses:" https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Comment: That's nice. Great thorough answer.